# Problems with javascript regex: replace exactly this number of letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having problems to define a regex in javascript. I want to replace format strings in [this format](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) (i.e. "dd/mm/yy") by strings in [this other format](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers) (i.e. "dd/MM/yyyy"). My problem is how to use javascript regex. For instance, how to convert the year? I've been trying to convert with these expressions:

```
f1 = "dd/mm/yy";
f1 = f1.replace(/[^y](yy)[^y]/g, 'yyyy');
f1 = f1.replace(/[^y](y)[^y]/g, 'yy');
```

With this I attempted to convert all 'yy' not sorrounded by any 'y' to 'yyyy' and then do the same with alone 'y', but I don't know how to say "*yy not sorrounded by any y*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the character before `y`, and refer back to it using `$1`. "The character before" can be anything except for `y`. It's also allowed to have nothing before the `y`, hence `|^`.
Prefix your pattern by `(?!y)`, which means "match if the next character does not equal `y`.

Adding both together:

```
f1 = "dd/mm/yy";
f1 = f1.replace(/([^y]|y)yy(?!y)/g, '$1yyyy');
f1 = f1.replace(/([^y]|^)y(?!y)/g, '$1yy');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match exactly two 'y's use `/\by{2}\b/` `\b` is a word boundary which will include the start of the string, the end of the string, and your '/'s (etc.).

Comment: Exactly, Rob W has pointed a non matching regex using word boundaries.

Comment: The regex matches what's mentioned, dd/mm/yyo strikes me as very contrived as you'd end up with something like 01/01/111 which makes no sense.